# Spark AnalysisException cannot resolve 'column name' given input columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame containing column x, y

```
x     y
1     false
1     false
1     true
2     true
2     false
3     null
3     true
```

I try to create a contingency table with the following code and expecting the result below:

```
myDataFrame.stat.crosstab("x", "y")

x_y  true    false     null
1    1       2         0
2    1       1         0
3    1       0         1
```

However, I get the following exception: `AnalysisException cannot resolve 'true' given input columns [x, y]`

The column 'true' (as well as 'false' and 'null') is created automatically by `stat.crosstab` at runtime. A static analysis cannot possibly detect the new column name without doing a full pass over the data first.

I am using Spark 1.6.1.5. Is this a bug? Can I disable the Analyzer somehow?